# Kivy: How to create a RecycleView that works dynamically

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to create my personal RecycleView widget.
But the result is displayed with some issues.

**Result**
[image: Result]

**Wrong result**
[image: Wrong result]

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string('''
<SelectableButton>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.9, 0.9, .9, .4) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<RV>:
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
    scroll_wheel_distance: dp(100)
    bar_width: dp(10)
    viewclass: 'SelectableButton'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: True
''')

nbre = 40
items_1 = ["fruits" + str(i) for i in range(nbre)]
items_2 = ["animaux" + str(i) for i in range(nbre)]
num = range(nbre)

class MyButton(Button):
    """ My Special Button """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.position = kwargs.get("position", (None, None))

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            super(MyButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)
            print ("Button {} is pressed on position {}".format(self.text, self.position))
            return False

class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, GridLayout):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    def __init__(self, nbre_cols=None, **kwargs):
        super(SelectableButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.index = None
        self.cols = nbre_cols
        self.selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def add_widget(self, child):
        print ("\tadd_widget {}".format(child.text))
        return super(SelectableButton, self).add_widget(child)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        self.cols = len(data) if not self.cols else self.cols
        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.add_widget(MyButton(text=data['item'+str(i)]['text'], position={'x': i, 'y': index}))

        return super(SelectableButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to line {1} {0}".format(rv.data[index], index))
        else:
            print("selection removed for line {1} {0}".format(rv.data[index], index))


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setData, 1)    

    def setData(self, data=None):
        self.data = [{'item0': {'text': str(n)}, 'item1': {'text': i1}, 'item2': {'text': i2}} for n, i1, i2 in zip(num, items_1, items_2)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

The purpose is to be able to dynamically display some data. I looked to some answers here and picked some part of the codes to create this. As viewclass I'm using a set of Button. The problem is that, the code seems to work  fine. But when I scroll down and up to see the data. The visual start to act pretty weird. This my code.

Comment: I can't get your code to run. Produces a `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters` at line 47: `super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)` coming from the `Widget` class.

Comment: I don't know why. Here it run without that issue.

Comment: Anyway I fugured a way to get the code working without the weird visual. It looks like everytime that the windows size is change or I scroll the recycleview duplicate the data displayed. so we just need to clear the widgets every time
`refresh_view_attrs is called`

`
def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.index = index
`